# Change a value within a list from a string to number

Tags: list-manipulation, import, replacement

I have a table with 10 columns. The last column contains a string; e.g.,

"center",  "passageway 1", up to  "passageway 8".

I want to change the last column so that the string is replaced with an assigned number, e.g,

```
"center" -> 0
"passageway 4" -> 4
```

I have added an image of the list. How I can change column J to numeric values as described above?

Thanks.

---

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
labels = Flatten@{"center", 
   Table["passageway " <> ToString[i], {i, 1, 8}]}
rules = MapThread[Rule, {labels, Range[0, Length@labels - 1]}]
```

> ```
> {"center" -> 0, "passageway 1" -> 1, "passageway 2" -> 2, 
>  "passageway 3" -> 3, "passageway 4" -> 4, "passageway 5" -> 5, 
>  "passageway 6" -> 6, "passageway 7" -> 7, "passageway 8" -> 8}
> ```

You can create these rules manually if programming them in is difficult due to a lack of a pattern.

---

Creating mock data template (fewer columns):

```
alist := {TimeObject[
   {RandomInteger[{1, 12}], RandomInteger[{0, 59}], 
    RandomInteger[{0, 59}]}
   ]
  , RandomInteger[{-1, -200}]
  , RandomInteger[{-10, 10}]
  , RandomChoice[labels]
  }
```

---

Test:

```
(blist = Table[alist, {10}]) // Grid
blist /. rules // Grid
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
{"center", "passageway 7", "passageway 13"} /.
  {"center" -> 0,
   s_String?(StringStartsQ["passageway "]) :> ToExpression[StringDrop[s, 11]]}

(*    {0, 7, 13}    *)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
list =
  {{10, "a", "cn"},
   {20, "b", "cn"},
   {30, "c", "pw 1"},
   {40, "d", "pw 1"},
   {50, "e", "pw 3"},
   {60, "e", "pw 3"},
   {70, "f", "pw 8"}};
```

```
Cases[{a__, b_} :> {a, ToExpression @ StringTake[b, -1]}] @
  ReplaceAll[{a__, "cn"} :> {a, "cn 0"}] @ list // TableForm
```

[image]